# SQLLite Update Statement by using JOIN Two Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I want to update my Product Table with a trigger after new tupple inserted in to detail_of_sale table.

I've searched about this problem and tried couple of solution ways but I couldn't solve it.

Here are my tables.

detail_of_sale(detailID,saleID,productID,quantity...)

product(productID, stock ...);

```
Create Trigger editQuantity AFTER INSERT ON detail_of_sale
BEGIN
Update product join detail_of_sale on
detail_of_sale.productID=product.productID set stock=stock-(Select quantity
from detail_of_sale where saleID=new.SaleID);
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a `join`, just references to the `new` table:

```
Update product 
    set stock = stock - new.quantity
    where productID = new.productID;
```

Comment: but there is no saleID attribute in my Product table.

Comment: @EmreSERBEST . . . That was the logic in the query your wrote.  Apparently, the right condition is on `productID`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution thats so clear answer, when I see your answer, I remembered once again I shouldn't think too complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Update product 
    set stock = stock - i.quantity
from product INNER JOIN inserted i on i.productid = productid
```